# How to pass values to an html page from google script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a google sheet, maintaining a list of projects, with some scripting running behind it. I have been able to add functionality to click an Add Project button which opens an HTML window for entering the information, and on submit, add a new record to the sheet.

Now I am working on a process to remove a record if the status is changed to Cancelled.  What I would like to do is show an html window listing certain details of the project, and give the user a chance to either go back without cancelling the project, or enter some notes as to why it's being cancelled and then continue.

Where I am stuck is populating the html window with the details of the project.  I have figured out one way to do it, but I know that this isn't the best way.

Google Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 9 && e.value == "Cancelled" && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Summary") {
    var cancelSheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName());
    var cancelRange = cancelSheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, cancelSheet.getLastColumn());
    var cancelRow = cancelRange.getValues();

    openCancelDialog(cancelRow);
  }
}

function openCancelDialog(x) {
  var html = HtmlService
  //.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Cancel')
  .createHtmlOutput(
    '<table><tr><td colspan = \"2\"><b>You are cancelling the following project:</b></td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>Project Name: </td><td>' + x[0][4] + '</td></tr>' + 
    '<tr><td>Project Number: </td><td>' + x[0][0] + '</td></tr>' + 
    '<tr><td>Project Category: </td><td>' + x[0][1] + '</td></tr>' + 
    '<tr><td>Business Owner: </td><td>' + x[0][17] + '</td></tr>' + 
    '<tr><td>Project Manager: </td><td>' + x[0][18] + '</td></tr>' + 
    '</table>'
  )
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .showModalDialog(html, 'Cancel a Project');
}
```

This way is writing the html directly in the gs.  What I'd like to do is have a separate html page that gets created.  That can be done with this method (and is how I'm creating the Add Project dialog elsewhere in the gs):

```
function openCancelDialog(x) {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Cancel').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .showModalDialog(html, 'Cancel a Project');
}
```

This would be Cancel.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
      <!-- Scripting to get my values? -->
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Layout the window
         Add a Comments section
         Add a button to go back without cancel
         Add a button to submit the cancel and update -->
  </body>
</html>
```

But what I haven't figured out is how to pass the array from the openCancelDialog function to the html, so it cab be shown on the page..

I suspect that I need to add scripting to the Cancel.html file to get those values.  But is there a way to send that array to the html while it's being created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kos's answer gave me some ideas on how I could work it out.  That, as well as some additional reading, especially https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp and the follow up sections, helped me figure this one out.

New js code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 9 && e.value == "Cancelled" && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Summary") {
    var cancelSheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName());
    var cancelRange = cancelSheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, cancelSheet.getLastColumn());
    var cancelRow = cancelRange.getValues();

    //openCancelDialog(cancelRow);

    var aSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
    var column = e.range.getColumn();
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    Logger.log("Col: " + column + "  Row: " + row + "  Sheet: " + aSheet);
    Logger.log(cancelRow);
  }
  Logger.log(e);
}

function openCancelDialog(row) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // get template
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Cancel');

  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(row);

  // pass data to template
  template.data = myJSON;

  // get output html
  var html = template.evaluate();

  // show modal window
  ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Cancel a Project');
}
```

New HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>  
    <table>
      <tr><td>Number: </td><td id="number"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Name: </td><td id="name"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Category: </td><td id="category"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Business Owner: </td><td id="owner"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Project : </td><td id="manager"></td></tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      var objII = JSON.parse(<?=data?>);

      document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = objII[0][0];
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = objII[0][4];
      document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = objII[0][1];
      document.getElementById("owner").innerHTML = objII[0][17];
      document.getElementById("manager").innerHTML = objII[0][18];
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I suspect there may be more elegant ways to do this, and probably even more "correct" ways.  But this seems to be working for what I needed it to do, so I figured I'd post it in case someone else was looking.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createtemplatefromfilefilename):

```
function openCancelDialog(row)
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // get template
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Cancel');

  // pass data to template
  template.data = {
    row: JSON.stringify(row)
  };

  // get output html
  var html = template.evaluate();

  // show modal window
  ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Cancel a Project');
}
```

Cancel.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    var row = <?!=data.row?>;
    //document.write(row);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Detailed template documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.  I like to do it this way because I have a lot more control than I do with templates.

This is a script that I did when I was working on an email example script that is contained in a spreadsheet. This script is a little less complicated because it's just for giving the user the option for removing sent emails from the emailsetup page and archiving them on another page.  It does it by creating html on the fly and collecting it as a string and then adding it to another page of html. I launch the html at the end of the script as a dialog that allows the users to select which emails to archive by checking checkboxes and clicking on a button called Archive Selected. I found it easier to put my javascript functions together in a standard html file and then run that through HtmlService first and append the string later.

Here's the script:

```
function archiveSelectedEmails()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('EmailSetup');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var s='<html><head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body>';
  var s='';
  for(var i=2;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    var dataA={};
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[1].length;j++)
    {
      dataA[rngA[1][j]]=rngA[i][j];
    }
    var row=Number(i+1);
    s+='<div id="row' + row + '"><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="' + Number(i+1) + '" />' + ' <strong>Row:</strong> ' + Number(i+1) + ' <strong>Name:</strong> ' + dataA.Name + ' <strong>Email:</strong> ' + dataA.Email + ' <strong>Subject:</strong> ' + dataA.Subject + ' <strong>DateSent:</strong> ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dataA.DateSent), 'GMT-6', "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + '</div>';
  }
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" /><input type="button" value="Archive Checked" onClick="getCheckedBoxes(\'email\');" />';

  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlToBody').setWidth(800).setHeight(250);
  html.append(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Select Emails to Archive');
}
```

Here's the html file 'htmlToBody':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
  var rowsToArchive = [];
  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) 
  {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
     {
        rowsToArchive.push(Number(checkboxes[i].value));
     }
  }
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
    .archiveSelectedRows(rowsToArchive);
}

function setResponse(a)
{
  var s='<br />Rows: ';
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    if(i>0)
    {
      s+=', ';
    }
    s+=a[i];
    var id='#row' + a[i]
    $(id).css('display','none');
  }
  s+='<br />Total: ' + a.length;
  google.script.run.displayMessage(s,'Archived Rows')
}
console.log('script here');
</script>
   </head>  
  <body>
```

I took your project idea and ran with it a little.

These are the google scripts.  You'll notice I started with the name of your function.

```
    function openCancelDialog1()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Projects');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var s='';
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    var dataA={};
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[0].length;j++)
    {
      dataA[rngA[0][j]]=rngA[i][j];
    }
    var row=Number(i+1);
    s+='<div id="row' + row + '"><input type="checkbox" name="project" value="' + row + '" />' + ' <strong>Row:</strong> ' + Number(i+1) + ' <strong>Name:</strong> ' + dataA.Name + ' <strong>Project:</strong> ' + dataA.Description + '</div>';
  }
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" /><input type="button" value="Cancel and Archive Checked" onClick="getCheckedBoxes(\'project\');" />';
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlToBody').setWidth(800).setHeight(250);
  html.append(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Select Project to Cancel');
}

function archiveSelectedRows(rows)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Projects');
  var dest=ss.getSheetByName('ArchivedProjects');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var deleted=[];
  for(var i=rngA.length-1;i>1;i--)
  {
    if(rows.indexOf(i+1)>-1)
    {
      deleted.push(Number(i+1));
      rngA[i][4]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-7', 'M/d/yyyy')
      dest.appendRow(rngA[i]);
      sht.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
  var msg='Row Numbers Deleted = ' + deleted;
  var title='Rows Deleted';
  var timeout=10;
  return deleted;
}

function displayMessage(msg,title)
{
  msg+='<br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close()"; />';
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msg).setWidth(400).setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, title);
}
```

This is the htmlTobody file.  It's been modified a bit for this situation.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
  var rowsToArchive = [];
  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) 
  {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
     {
        rowsToArchive.push(Number(checkboxes[i].value));
     }
  }
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
    .archiveSelectedRows(rowsToArchive);
}

function setResponse(a)
{
  var s='<br />Row Numberss: ';
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    if(i>0)
    {
      s+=', ';
    }
    s+=a[i];
    var id='#row' + a[i]
    $(id).css('display','none');
  }
  s+='<br />Total: ' + a.length;
  google.script.run.displayMessage(s,'Canceled Rows')
}
console.log('script here');
</script>
   </head>  
  <body>
```

And this is what my 'Projects' tab looks like. And I have a Projects tab and an ArchivedProjects tab.  When I archive the projects they get copied into the ArchivedProjects sheet.

[image]