# Google Apps Script not receiving multiple checkbox selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-apps-script

I have a WebApp that receives form data. Part of that data is from check boxes:

```
<form id="intakeForm" class="labels-hidden-form custom-form" action="/new-patient-form/"
enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">   
    <input type="checkbox" name="intake_symptoms" value="coughing">Coughing<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="intake_symptoms" value="sneezing">Sneezing<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="intake_symptoms" value="vomiting">Vomiting<br>
```

I'm using the following function to serialize all of the form data to send to the GAS.

```
  (function ($, a) {
    $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
      var b = {};
      $.each(this.serializeArray(), function (d, e) {
        var f = e.name,
          c = e.value;
        b[f] = b[f] === a ? c : $.isArray(b[f]) ? b[f].concat(c) : [b[f], c];
      });
      return b;
    };
  })(jQuery);
```

when I `console.log` the object created by the function above, it displays s expected:

> intake_symptoms: (2) ["Coughing", "Vomiting"]

however when I send the values back in the response from the GAS and `console.log` the object it only shows the first checked box

> intake_symptoms[]: "Coughing"

This is the code I use to send the submitted values back to the web page

```
function doGet(e) {
  var params = e.parameter
  var result = {};
  try {
    result = {
      status: start(params),
      rawVals: params,
      errs: errors
    }
  } catch (f) {
    result.error = f.toString();
  }
  return ContentService     
  .createTextOutput(e.parameters.callback + '(' + JSON.stringify(result) + ')')
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

I'm at a loss here. Do I need to send the checkbox values to my script in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

```
var params = e.parameter
```

- `e.parameter` only returns  the first value

#### Solution:

- Use `e.parameters` instead.

#### References:

- [Web App#Request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

#### Snippet:

```
var params = e.parameters;//modified
```

Comment: it's worth mentioning that `e.parameters` returns **ALL** of the values as `Object` not `String` (like `e.parameter` does) even if there is only a single value... like say from a standard text input. So you have to convert to String if you do any further manipulation. `e.parameters.intake_patient_lname.toString().toUpperCase()`

Comment: @Daveh0 The object will always be a array and wherever string is required , the array will be implicitly converted to string.

Comment: that's what I would have expected, but trying to do  `e.parameters.intake_patient_lname.toString().toUpperCase()` produced the following error: `TypeError: Cannot find function toUpperCase in object Johnson`. Calling `toString()` eliminates the error.

Comment: @Dave You should use `e.parameters.intake_patient_lname[0].toUpperCase() `

Comment: Got it. So the value DOES need to be accessed differently when using `e.params` than when using `e.param`. And yes referencing the 1st array item that is in fact a `String` makes more sense than converting the array. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**Getting multiple checkboxes**

```
<script>
  function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
  var rowsToArchive = [];
  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) 
  {
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
     {
        rowsToArchive.push(Number(checkboxes[i].value));
     }
  }
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
    .archiveSelectedRows(rowsToArchive);
}
</script>
```

From this [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853976/7215091)